# Presenting UIActivityViewController upside down

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rotation, uiactivityviewcontroller

In simulator and on the iPhone, in iOS 6 and iOS 7, I've noticed that `UIActivityViewController` doesn't rotate upside down. It doesn't matter if I present it from a general viewController or from the root.

This behavior messes up my interface...

Untill now, my best try it is to prevent `UIActivityViewController` from being presented when the device is upside down and to block rotation when `UIActivityViewController` is presented. Anyway, I can't find any reference to this issue.

Is this behavior expected?
Do you know any better approach to avoid this behavior, or a better way to prevent my interface from corruption?

Comment: have you figure out the solution? i am also looking for same issue but didnot get the justified answer

Comment: Even i am also facing the same issue. Could you please let me know if you are able to fix this or not..

Comment: No, unfortunately not yet...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make all rotations of UIActivityViewController, because it is a subclass of UIViewController, that has rotation methods.

1) In Your **UIActivityViewController.m** file add method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

AND

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

2) in Your info.plist check if Your application supports orientation, You want.

In iOS 6 and later, your app supports the interface orientations defined in your app’s Info.plist file. A view controller can override the supportedInterfaceOrientations method to limit the list of supported orientations. Typically, the system calls this method only on the root view controller of the window or a view controller presented to fill the entire screen; child view controllers use the portion of the window provided for them by their parent view controller and no longer participate directly in decisions about what rotations are supported.

**The intersection of the app’s orientation mask and the view controller’s orientation mask is used to determine which orientations a view controller can be rotated into.****